# React Native load dynamic content onto webview

Tags: react-native, webview

Currently I am loading a html file from my android assets folder into webview.

dashboard.html file contains some scripts.
if its static it works fine.

```
<WebView
  ref={(component) => (this.webview = component)}
  style={{ height: height * 1.3 }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  source={{uri:'file:///android_asset/graph/pages/dashboard.html'}}
  startInLoadingState={true}
  javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
  mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
/>
```

But I need to dynamically update a variable in my script.
How can I access scripts placed in assets folder from react-native component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forceUpdate();
e.g.

```
<webView source={{html: this.state.html}}></webView>

onTestBtnClicked() {
    const html = '<div>test1</div>';
    this.setState({ html });
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't access and update a script file but maybe you can run your script or extra code once the WebView is loaded using the injectedJavaScript prop

Example:

```
const injectedJs = `
    alert("My custom code will go here!");
`;

return (
    <WebView
    ref={(component) => (this.webview = component)}
    style={{ height: height * 1.3 }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    source={{uri:'file:///android_asset/graph/pages/dashboard.html'}}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
    mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
    injectedJavaScript={injectedJs}
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
    />
);
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to update script before loading the webview.
Is there any other  way to load local file into webview other than placing files into assets folder.

Comment: Maybe you can use injectJavaScript function which allows you to run the script at the exact time you call it. You can create a function like

alertMessage = () => {
   
  }

and the call the above on the webview's onLoadStart event.
If you want to make changes to the script I suggest you inject it with one of the two  ways mentioned.